# Dot net and java application connected through ESB?

Tags: java, .net, esb

There is web App_1 which is on dot net while another web App_2 is on java. App_1 need to interact with App_2.

App_1 can be inter or intra company application.

My question is does in general prominent ESB products provides the way dot net application send the dot net specific object/message on channel, then
transformer transform the dot net object to java object and put it on channel_2 like below image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is “yes” and here is a list of some products that allow communication between applications via an ESB:

[jnbridge](https://jnbridge.com/software/jnbridgepro/overview/?utm_campaign=217739905&utm_source=g&utm_medium=15189019705&utm_term=%2Bjava%20%2B.net&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIt_iYrfW22AIVGrbACh2agABzEAAYASAAEgICK_D_BwE)

[talend](http://searchmicroservices.techtarget.com/feature/For-data-oriented-app-integration-look-toward-Talend-ESB)

Talend ESB allows communication via web services so this may or may not be precisely what you are looking for in your architecture.